# Cannot write correctly JQuery .load()

Tags: jquery

I have some problems with .load()
I have table in html with list of printers(ip -ddresses) and would like to add  the extra column where to get current status of toner.
when i run this jquery on its page - it shows me correctly.

```
if($("#machine .word-wrap:contains('Cartridge')").text()=="")
    console.log ("OK"); else $("#machine .word-wrap:contains('Cartridge')").text();
```

when I run this code on the list page
it doesn't show me status

```
$("#status").load("http://10.29.96.11 #machine .word-wrap:contains('Cartridge')").text();
```

In html I have `<td id="status"></td>`

Please help me find my mistake.
Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/: *"Additional Notes: Due to browser security restrictions, most 'Ajax' requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol."* __Could this be the case?__